# outbuilding drain into dry well

Tags: drainage, rain, drains

Aside from code differences between jurisdictions, is it acceptable to tie an outbuilding floor drain into a dry well drainage system? The outbuilding does not have a water supply, the slope of the surrounding area allows water to seep in under a rollup door. The slope cannot be altered.

Examples from local jurisdictions would be welcome. (I know, ask my local code enforcement, yada yada ... )

Comment: You could also consider a grated trough outside of the door, if it's practical.

Comment: Good idea, thanks. There is a grated trough drain that will be replaced and also tied to the dry well.